# Hive ParseException - cannot recognize input near 'end' 'string'

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting the following error when trying to create a Hive table from an existing DynamoDB table:

```
NoViableAltException(88@[])
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.identifier(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9123)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.identifier(HiveParser.java:30750)
...more stack trace...
FAILED: ParseException line 1:77 cannot recognize input near 'end' 'string' ',' in column specification
```

The query looks like this (simplified to protect the innocent):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE moveProjects (cid string, end string, category string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "Projects",
    "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "cid:cid,end:end,category:category");
```

Basically, I am trying to create a Hive table containing the contents of the `Projects` DynamoDB table, but the create statement is throwing a parse error from Hive / Hadoop.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The issue isn't actually a syntax error, the Hive ParseException is just caused by a reserved keyword in Hive (in this case, `end`).

The solution: use backticks around the offending column name:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE moveProjects (cid string, `end` string, category string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "Projects",
    "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "cid:cid,end:end,category:category");
```

With the added backticks around `end`, the query works as expected.

#### Reserved words in Amazon Hive (as of February 2013):

> IF, HAVING, WHERE, SELECT, UNIQUEJOIN, JOIN, ON, TRANSFORM, MAP, REDUCE, TABLESAMPLE, CAST, FUNCTION, EXTENDED, CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE, END, DATABASE, CROSS

Source: [This Hive ticket from the Facebook Phabricator tracker](https://reviews.facebook.net/D8397)

Comment: I meet similar issue when using column _1. change to another name solves the problem. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: "div" was another keyword. Replaced with backticks and started working.. !! 

Error Message:    FAILED: ParseException line 52:16 cannot recognize input near 'div' 'STRING' ',' in column specification

Answer (score 3):

You can always escape the reserved keyword if you still want to make your query work!!

Just replace **end** with **`end`**

Here is the list of reserved keywords 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE moveProjects (cid string, `end` string, category string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "Projects",
    "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "cid:cid,end:end,category:category");
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using /Date=20161003 in the folder path while doing an insert overwrite and it was failing. I changed it to /Dt=20161003 and it worked

Comment: Do you know how we can partition on /20161003 ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing like that:

**insert into my_table(my_field_0, ..., my_field_n) values(my_value_0, ..., my_value_n)**