# Parse Error- NoViableAltException found when running apache hive

Tags: hive

```
NoViableAltException(26@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1074)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
        at `enter code here`org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:311)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:425)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 cannot recognize input near 'MERGE' 'INTO' 'scrap_data'

Getting the above exception. in order to resolve the same issue, i have fallowed 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640760/hive-parseexception-cannot-recognize-input-near-end-string

As per this blog. i made the changes but did not work for me.
Help me with this issue. `enter code here`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbALPartNr(
pn_id int,
category int,
pn varchar(30),
price decimal(18, 8),
pn_desc varchar(500),
scrap_limit smallint,
scrap_percent decimal(18, 0),
price_limit decimal(18, 8),
plant_name varchar(250)
)
MERGE INTO scrap_data.tbALPartNr t
USING(SELECT distinct[scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn],
count([scrap_data.tbALPartNr.plant_name])as plants
FROM scrap_data.tbALPartNr group by [scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn]) s
ON (t.scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn=s.scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t.category=s.plants;
```

Above is the code i have in my .hql script. when i am running the script getting above error could you please help me with this.
found the same kind issue in the below blog but did not help to resolve my issue.
[Hive ParseException - cannot recognize input near 'end' 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640760/hive-parseexception-cannot-recognize-input-near-end-string)

without this logic the script is working fine.

```
MERGE INTO scrap_data.tbALPartNr t
    USING(SELECT distinct[scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn],
    count([scrap_data.tbALPartNr.plant_name])as plants
    FROM scrap_data.tbALPartNr group by [scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn]) s
    ON (t.scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn=s.scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.category=s.plants;
```

Any one help with this.

Comment: are you sure there is support for merge in hive? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10924 The issue here is still unresolved

Comment: Roshini I am not sure ab the MERGE support in HIVE.. is that still .     MERGE INTO scrap_data.tbALPartNr t
USING(SELECT distinct[scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn],
count([scrap_data.tbALPartNr.plant_name])as plants
FROM scrap_data.tbALPartNr group by [scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn]) s
ON (t.scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn=s.scrap_data.tbALPartNr.pn)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t.category=s.plants;

Comment: well if there is no merge support then you can't do that in hive. :/ It means that keyword doesn't exist for hive. (I am not sure I couldn't find this in the documentation but then again I didn't look hard enough..just a simple google....I assumed you would know since you are using it)

Comment: yes, i googled it. i did not find any syntax with merge or any transformations done in hive using merge. this is the first time i m trying to use it.but not unable to proceed further after this error. if get to know abt the usage of it. please write on this page.thanks in advance

Comment: well according to the jira it should be available in the next version of hive....so if you keep track of it you will know. Can you please choose the next comment as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

This issues has not been resolved:  issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10924  The current functionality does not exist in hive.